# organizing unit tests in groups in visual studio test explorer

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution with about 70 projects in visual studio. The solution also contains several unit test projects. Visual studio displays my tests in the test explorer as following:

```
Run | Run ... |
> Passed tests
v Failed tests
* test1
* test2
> Not run tests
```

all tests are thrown together, and the only way i can think of organizing this screen is using a naming convention for the tests.

I would like to avoid that. Is there any way where i can organize the tests into a group or node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Traits to group your tests.
With Traits, you can for example, group by Category or Priority and run only these tests.

Here is a good link you can see how to implement: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/09/how-to-manage-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-part-1-using-traits-in-the-unit-test-explorer.aspx

Comment: Link is now dead.

Answer (score 4):

Right clicking on tests will give you an option to group tests by different categories. Or, you can create several Playlist by right clicking tests in Test Explorer as well. Tests can be added to different Playlist.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using NUnit you can add a category attribute to tests like so: [Category("foo")]

In the Test Explorer window you can select to group by traits.